# Cant connect to wifi network in ubuntu after windows 10 upgrade from windows 8.1

Tags: networking, wireless, dual-boot

I have both Windows 8.1 and Ubuntu installed on my computer. I was able to connect to WiFi networks on both the OS's. I recently upgraded my Windows 8.1 to Windows 10 and when I booted into Ubuntu afterwards I wasn't able to connect to WiFi on Ubuntu any more but I can still connect on Windows 10.

I looked on the internet for a solution and after a while I decided to go back to Windows 8.1 hoping it would solve the problem. But it didn't. I can still connect to WiFi networks using Windows 8.1, but the situation hasn't changed in Ubuntu. I re-installed Ubuntu but nothing changed. I even booted up using a Linux live disc and I faced the same problem. I can see all the WiFi networks listed, and when I try to connect, it just keeps trying for a while and then fails.

The output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2` is:

```
04:00.0 Network Controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros AR9485 Wireless Network Adapter [168c:0032] (rev 01)
          Subsystem: Lenovo Devide [17aa:3218]
          Kernel driver in use: ath9k
```

*How should I proceed?*

EDIT: I could actually connect to wi-fi on ubuntu today. Not sure why or if it's gonna stay this way.

UPDATE: Turned out to be a fluke.

UPDATE: Turns out I can actually connect to wifi networks on ubuntu. I'm just unable to connect to the wifi network at my workplace. I can connect to it on windows however.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2` terminal command.

Comment: What probably (99% sure) happened is that your Win10 upgraded the **firmware** of your Qualcomm Atheros AR9485 to a version that isn't supported by Ubuntu.  I'll drop by our chat room and ask whether our resident WiFi expert knows how to downgrade the firmware of your chip or upgrade the Qualcomm module to a development version.

Comment: Thank you Fabby. That would be great help. Please do let me know.

Answer (score 1):

I just recently ran into this issue when I upgraded to windows 10 as well. Mine was with the wired ethernet though. I had to boot into windows 10, go to my intel ethernet settings. I unchecked the 3/4 checked options for WOL(Wake On Lan). Rebooted into ubuntu and its running perfectly now. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. 
Unfortunately I have no idea what to do with wi-fi. I already unchecked wi-fi sense hoping it might change something but so far, it hasn't worked.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem

Maybe it's coincidence, but I uninstalled the antivirus on Windows 10 (Avast) and returned the wireless internet to my computer

Now it's working fine. I'll reboot on Windows to see if it's sill working on Ubuntu